# what is the input to the reset port in the unit delay ressetable block in Simulink?

Tags: matlab, block, delay, simulink

I am building a block for this equation Y_New= Lambda*(X_t) + (1-lambda)*Y_old,
I would like to have Y_old as the delayed value by one step to Y_New .. and this to happen continuously.´. and not only one time.. so i have the value of Y_old updated every time Y_New changes ... If just a unit delay block.. it does not give me the right answer.. what i am thinking of is the unit delay reset.. but i do not know what is the Input of the reset port.. I connected it to am if Action Subsystem but it gives me an error that i can only connect the if Action Subsystem to one port.. i want to link the unit delay reset to an if condition that results if it is true then update Y_old.. if not Y_New = Y_old[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrTn7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you describe, I do not think you need the reset port. You should turn off the reset port and place the Delay block inside an enabled sub-system. Whenever the enable signal is on delay will update with a new value otherwise, it will hold on to the existing value. I assume you have some signal which tells when y signal has new value.

If your y signal is updated each time step then you should not use enabled subsystem. It is simpler to just use the delay without reset port. At each time step when you get a new value, delay will update with the new value and will output the old value.